# 'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get' - Digital ocean

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I have made a deplyoment to Digital ocean, on staging (Heroku server) the app is working well, but Digital ocean it's failing with the error below, what could be the issue :

```
AttributeError at /admin/
'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://xxxx/admin/
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/markdown/util.py, line 85, in <module>
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.5
Python Path:    
['/opt/app',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/odf']
Server time:    Sun, 02 Oct 2022 21:41:00 +0000
```

Comment: can you paste the url for the source of markdown here please?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Because `importlib-metadata` releases v5.0.0 yesterday which it remove deprecated endpoint.

You can set `importlib-metadata<5.0` in ur setup.py so it does not install latest version.

Or if you use requirements.txt, you can as well set `importlib-metadata` below version `5.0` e.g `importlib-metadata==4.13.0`

For more info: https://importlib-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html

Comment: This works, thanks. I notice that `importlib-metadata` is in the stack trace of errors and decided to try out your solution.

Comment: Am still confused about setup.py, since am using Django with requirements.txt is this where am supposed to set `importlib-metadata==4.13.0` ?

Comment: It worked finally

Comment: This also creates an issue when using xarray.open_dataset()

Comment: This also solved a similar issue I had with `python3.7` and `bandit==1.7.1`

Comment: Solved issue with `celery` with shadow installation of latest version of `import-lib`

Comment: `!pip install importlib-metadata==4.13.0` will solve the problem. It will also work for those having issues getting xarray to work in Google Colab.

Comment: has this been fixed in v6.0.0?

Answer (score 16):

As importlib-metadata released v5.0.0, it removed the deprecated endpoint. So Use the older version and do not install the latest version.

```
!pip install importlib-metadata==4.13.0
```

Use this in the terminal/Collab to get an older version(v4.13.0).

Comment: `!pip install importlib-metadata==4.13.0` will solve the problem. It will also work for those having issues getting xarray to work in Google Colab

Answer (score 13):

If you are using certain forks of [Redash](https://github.com/mozilla/redash) or even the official [Redash](https://github.com/getredash/redash), you need to pin its `importlib-metadata` to `4.12.0` in the [requirements_bundles.txt](https://github.com/mozilla/redash/blob/97154bb62d3b0d98cd4922677fd062966202387d/requirements_bundles.txt#L9)

Answer (score 8):

I was running Django on Google App Engine and encountered the same error.

I checked the source and found that the error occurred in a built-in python function.

I updated to Python 3.9 and the error was resolved.

I was originally using python 3.7.

I don't know if this helps, but FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Zach answer:

If you are using certain forks of [Redash](https://github.com/getredash/redash) or even the official Redash, you need to pin its **importlib-metadata** to 4.13.0 in the [requirements_bundles.txt](https://github.com/mozilla/redash/blob/97154bb62d3b0d98cd4922677fd062966202387d/requirements_bundles.txt#L9).

If you are running on docker, don't forget to rebuild your docker containers.

```
docker-compose build 
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your [flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8). The newest versions do not hit this issue – @AmaJayJB

- ['EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get' during running pre-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75591296/entrypoints-object-has-no-attribute-get-during-running-pre-commit#comment136872204_75591296)