# Unable to start MLflow UI

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyarrow, mlflow, python-importlib

**Problem:** Following a quicksart guide in official docs (https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking/autolog.html), every time I try running `mlflow ui --port 8080` inside parent directory with particular conda env activated same error keeps popping up:

```
C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\regular\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_config.py:322: UserWarning: Valid config keys have changed in V2:
* 'schema_extra' has been renamed to 'json_schema_extra'
  warnings.warn(message, UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\regular\Scripts\mlflow.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>  
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\regular\Lib\site-packages\mlflow\cli.py", line 356, in <module>
    type=click.Choice([e.name for e in importlib.metadata.entry_points().get("mlflow.app", [])]),   
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have tried multiple versions, reinstalling `importlib-metadata` (following same issue ['EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get' - Digital ocean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73929564/entrypoints-object-has-no-attribute-get-digital-ocean)), installing older versions prior to `mlflow=2.10.0` as well as older versions of `pydantic` prior to `pydantic==2.6.1` (following the advice of @BenWilson2 from DataBricks on MLflow GH issues). Would really appreciate if anyone could help me wrap my head around the issue. Thanks in advance.

**Project structure:**

[image]

**regModel.py**:

```py
import warnings
import argparse
import logging
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import mlflow
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARN)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

#evaluation function
def eval_metrics(actual, pred):
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(actual, pred))
    mae = mean_absolute_error(actual, pred)
    r2 = r2_score(actual, pred)
    return rmse, mae, r2


def run_experiment(alpha, l1_ratio):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

    # Read the wine-quality csv file from local
    data = pd.read_csv("data/red-wine-quality.csv")
    data.to_csv("data/red-wine-quality.csv", index=False)

    # Split the data into training and test sets. (0.75, 0.25) split.
    train, test = train_test_split(data)

    # The predicted column is "quality" which is a scalar from [3, 9]
    train_x = train.drop(["quality"], axis=1)
    test_x = test.drop(["quality"], axis=1)
    train_y = train[["quality"]]
    test_y = test[["quality"]]

    lr = ElasticNet(alpha=alpha, l1_ratio=l1_ratio, random_state=42)
    lr.fit(train_x, train_y)

    predicted_qualities = lr.predict(test_x)

    (rmse, mae, r2) = eval_metrics(test_y, predicted_qualities)

    print("Elasticnet model (alpha={:f}, l1_ratio={:f}):".format(alpha, l1_ratio))
    print("  RMSE: %s" % rmse)
    print("  MAE: %s" % mae)
    print("  R2: %s" % r2)
    mlflow.log_param("alpha", alpha)
    mlflow.log_param("l1", l1_ratio)
    mlflow.log_metric("rmse", rmse)
    mlflow.log_metric("r2", r2)
    mlflow.log_metric("mae", mae)
    mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr, "models")
```

**inroduction.ipynb**:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the error was in `cli.py`. However the appropriate fix was needed, which, thanks to [Gabomfim](https://github.com/Gabomfim), has been discovered:

> just substitute `.get("mlflow.app", [])` by `.select(group="mlflow.app")`

Answer (score 1):

> installing older versions prior to `mlflow=2.10.0` as well as older versions of `pydantic` prior to `pydantic==2.6.1`

Check if the issue is related to [`importlib-metadata`](https://github.com/python/importlib_metadata), as in [this article](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/entrypoints-object-has-no-attribute-get) from [Borislav Hadzhiev](https://bobbyhadz.com/about).

```
!pip install importlib-metadata==4.13.0
# or
!pip install importlib-metadata<5.0
```

Or you would need to *upgrade* other dependencies, as [`golosegor/pyspark-nested-fields-functions` had to do](https://github.com/golosegor/pyspark-nested-fields-functions/commit/3e36088f6b3c333176788c01fcfb2ecaa7b37d3e#diff-4d7c51b1efe9043e44439a949dfd92e5827321b34082903477fd04876edb7552) to avoid the same error.
(From [PR #1](https://github.com/golosegor/pyspark-nested-fields-functions/pull/1), referencing [`importlib_metadata` issue 406](https://github.com/python/importlib_metadata/issues/406))

---

[`mlflow/mlflow` issue 10804](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/10804) suggests:

> Hardcoding `endpoint_type` in [`metrics/genai/model_utils.py`](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/b4067669d241131cf1d36451146802b01ace977c/mlflow/metrics/genai/model_utils.py) like below seems to resolve the issue.
> Not sure of the explanation for why it is expecting `Endpoint` to have a `get` method.
>
> ```py
> client = get_deploy_client()
>
> endpoint = client.get_endpoint(deployment_uri)
> # endpoint_type = endpoint.get("task", endpoint.get("endpoint_type"))
> endpoint_type = "llm/v1/completions"
> ```